# Read more tag not working on page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Not sure what is wrong here as have found the same fix all over the place for my issue. Read more tags are not showing on my page that pulls in the latest posts. I have researched that simply adding this code will fix that.

```
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
?>
//The code must be inserted ahead of the call to the content

<?php the_content('Continue Reading'); ?>
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. Any other ideas or am I just using the code wrong, quote possible! Here is an idea of my page, any help in identifying where to insert the code would be much appreciated. Thanks very much guys!

```
 get_header(); ?>

 <div id="primary" class="site-content">
 <div id="content" role="main">
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
     <div class="entry-page-image">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-page-image -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'front' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.code.check wether you have given insert more tag in admin for pages and post

```
get_header(); ?>

 <div id="primary" class="site-content">
 <div id="content" role="main">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
 <div class="entry-page-image">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-page-image -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php 
        global $more;
    $more = 0;

 get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

 </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'front' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```